# Add value in json in each records

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, json, .net

I have json format as below. In that I have multiple records coming, check below json.

```
{
   "metadata":{
      "TotalCount":11,
      "CurrentPageNumber":1,
   },
   "records":[
      {
         "offerId":"e1b75d86-67b1-4557-a381-5474383da3fb",
         "isContract":true,
         "transportRouteId":"e1b75d86-67b1-4557-a381-5474383da3fb",
         "transportOrderId":"SEZYMY-210720-010097",
         "schedule":null,
      },
]
}
```

Now I want to add new value in each this records array, so how can I do that.

I want to add this value : ("carrierExpiredDate", (carrierExpiredDate.ComplianceExpiryDate.Value).Date);

So this new json should look like this.

```
{
   "metadata":{
      "TotalCount":11,
      "CurrentPageNumber":1,
   },
   "records":[
      {
         "offerId":"e1b75d86-67b1-4557-a381-5474383da3fb",
         "isContract":true,
         "transportRouteId":"e1b75d86-67b1-4557-a381-5474383da3fb",
         "transportOrderId":"SEZYMY-210720-010097",
         "schedule":null,
         "carrierExpiredDate": (carrierExpiredDate.ComplianceExpiryDate.Value).Date)
      },
]
}
```

Comment: Are you writing to Json file. Where it is stored?

Comment: @ziakhan I am getting json string in this way : var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var json = 
    @"{
   "metadata":{
      "TotalCount":11,
      "CurrentPageNumber":1,
   },
   "records":[
      {
         "offerId":"e1b75d86-67b1-4557-a381-5474383da3fb",
         "isContract":true,
         "transportRouteId":"e1b75d86-67b1-4557-a381-5474383da3fb",
         "transportOrderId":"SEZYMY-210720-010097",
         "schedule":null
      },
]
}";    

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var jList=jObject["records"].Children().ToList();
foreach(var jtoken in jList)
{
   jtoken["carrierExpiredDat"] = (carrierExpiredDate.ComplianceExpiryDate.Value).Date));
}
   string output = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: After foreach loop I need to convert this again in json string, because I tried your code but not adding new node in current json string.

Comment: See edited answer. Check if output contains your new key.

Comment: The output working as expected. Check on your side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The code was tested using Visual Studio and Postman

```
.....
var expDate=DateTime.Now;

var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
var deserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransportRoot>(json);
deserializedJson.Records.ForEach(i=> i.carrierExpiredDate=expDate);
var newJson= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedJson);
```

classes

```
   public class Metadata
   {
       public int TotalCount { get; set; }
       public int CurrentPageNumber { get; set; }
   }

   public class Record
   {
       public string offerId { get; set; }
       public bool isContract { get; set; }
       public string transportRouteId { get; set; }
       public string transportOrderId { get; set; }
       public object schedule { get; set; },
     public object carrierExpiredDate { get; set; }
   }

   public class TransportRoot
   {
       public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
       public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
   }
```

if you have a problem with a camel case json, I highly recommend to change your startup

```
    services.AddControllers()
   // or services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Comment: I am getting this error : JObject does not contain definition for 'Records'

Comment: @Nic did you use my classes? This code was tested and everything works.  And I don't know what is JObject. I don't have it my code. Pls explain.

Comment: @Nic It could be casing problem. Read my answer, or if you don' t want this,  change Records to records , and  Metadata to metadata  in my classes